# Can we Install Tails & Linux on same pen drive?

Tags: linux, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, tails

i got 32GB pen drive which i wanna use for Linux & tails by partitioning,can i make partitions in it and run both from same pen drive,I'm using windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you tried to google this? Any problems with solutions you've found?

Comment: i searched found that two pen drives are needed, as bootable media is needed for linux.

Comment: found on tecmint.com                                                                                           "You have to make two partitions on your Main USB drive using Gparted or Gnome Disk Utility, etc.

    The root partition of format ext4 of size according to your use.
    Optionally you can use the rest of the space as a FAT partition for using it as a normal USB drive.

I am having 16GB USB drive and I have created one root partition of 5GB and using rest 11GB as normal FAT partition. So my 16 GB USB drive is converted to 11GB drive for normal use on any PC."

Comment: so when a partition can be left for further use, can we use it for tails installation.

Answer (score 0):

### Full Install Ubuntu USB with Tails Persistent ISO Option

There are various methods of making a Ubuntu Full install that boots in both BIOS and UEFI mode: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

The simplest method is to flash a Full install image to the USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280737/how-should-i-make-my-partitions-for-a-full-install-usb/1280812#1280812

Once the Full install USB has been created, expand the FAT32/NTFS Data partition to fit the Tails ISO file, copy the ISO file to the USB.

Copy The Tails menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` on the USB

```
menuentry "Tails-4.12-ISO"{
    set isofile="/iso/tails-amd64-4.12.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live config live-media=removable nopersistence noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash noautologin module=Tails slab_nomerge slub_debug=FZP mce=0 vsyscall=none page_poison=1 quiet findiso=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

Boot the Full install USB and run `sudo update=grub` to add Tails to your boot menu.

Note that the menuentry will vary with the version of Tails.

Ref: https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/usb_install_and_upgrade/archive/

**Persistence**

If you start Tails from a USB stick, you can create a Persistent Storage in the free space left on the USB stick. The files and settings stored in the Persistent Storage are saved encrypted and remain available across different working sessions.

See: https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/index.en.html

Neither Rufus, balenaEtcher or gnome-disk provide for Persistence in Tails.

Comment: thanx for answer,i'm gonna try this and give update.

Comment: I Did Full install image to usb,now its not visible in My computer,i tried to change letter in disk management but its not helping, Did i miss something, it took me 3 days to make partitions in my usb because i didn't know about partitioning and function of rufus that it can make partitions before flashing, so what do i do now :(

Comment: Have you tried the pendrive on another computer? Is Windows Fast Boot/Secure boot turned off? See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot